# Visual Studio 2012 adding a database and creating first table named users

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express and have a razor c#.net project set up.

I have right clicked on AppData and added a Microsoft SQL database and named it "EspressoCoffees"

Now I can see that it is there, I goto the Database Explorer and right click on Tables and click add table.

The table designer comes up and I make a few columns making sure "Id" remains primary key.

1. Where on earth do I name the table? There is a table properties panel which I can't edit the name in as it is greyed out?
2. When I save the table it makes me choose the location for the file, what file is this? The table or the database???
3. **If I save the SQL file in the app data part... It doesn't appear under the Tables folder any way.**

Comment: Whenever I try to save my tables in Visual Studio 2012 Express, I save the table in the app data folder and the database UI never sees the new table!??!

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I am sick of having to do a forced "Save As..." starting from "My Documents" to save (and overwrite) my updated .sql file into my preferred projects directory every single time. I've probably done it about 100-200 times now (no kidding, real numbers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just modify the name of the table in the generated T-SQL and click on the "Update" button (int the top-left corner of the tab).

[image]

Comment: But is there a way to do it through the UI? I want to make sure that I'm not missing out on something simple here?

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that every time you load it up and change it, it keeps asking for a "Save As..." location, there seems to be no way to tell it to always save to a particular folder. I keep saving it in my projects folder, but every time i make a change, the folders dialog box pops up pointing me to "My Documents" and then i need to navigate and save at and overwrite to my usual location, and it keeps asking if i want to overwrite (tedious) and you can't change the folder/file path for the "Script File:" column basically. This problem I've had for days (& it seems @JamesT has too).

Comment: @josemigualtorres do you have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: You also need to update the table view. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618188/cannot-create-new-sql-data-tables-in-visual-studio-express-2012

Answer (score 1):

After you click update, close the design tab and hit refresh on the server explorer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Without creating the table use Queries to create the table
2. Update table in T-SQL .
   Simple as that ....