# Cannot create new SQL data tables in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have created a new SQL database in my Visual Studio Express 2012 website. This appears in the AppData folder. I can open the database in the Database explorer and now I want to add some empty data tables.

I right click on the Tables folder and select Add New Table. I get the screen (below). When I have finished I click Update and it appears to do something but then the table has not appeared in the Tables folder.

I have also tried clicking the save button, and saving the table manually in the AppData folder, but yet it still does not appear in the Tables folder.

What am I doing wrong please?

[image: enScreenshot of Table Creation window in VS Express 2012]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing the tables list on the right hand side?

Comment: I think its the curse if you do it yourserlf it doesnt work, when somebody tells you to do it it works. It is working now. Thank you for your help

Comment: np, oh if only i had an upvote for everytime this has happened to me :-)

Comment: @DavidMuller I think so, because when I happened to stumble across this answer the same thing happened to me!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwA-tNvU3hw

Steps 1-Change the name of table [dbo].[table---(change this)]

Step 2-Don't save the table after creating them rather choose option update table and then update database.

Step 3-On refreshing the tables you will be able to see your table.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, Visual Studio was saving the table to my documents. It should be writing the table to the MDF file. I used the designer to generate the T-SQL, then I copied the T-SQL right clicked on the tables folder, chose 'New Query' pasted the T-SQL commands, set the target database as shown in the image and ran the query. Finally!

In the 'New Query' window within VS 2012 Express, there is an 'available databases' drop down. Choose your database that is part of your solution and execute the T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Make following change:
CREATE TABLE [dbo][**change_this_name**] 
click the update button on top left corner.

Comment: Sure, this works if you type it in manually, but it does not solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I was up against this same problem in Visual Studio 2013 Community.  The solution was to go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and then download the SQL server compact / sql lite toolbox.  VS2013 will prompt you to restart for the new extension to take effect.

After the restart, your databases will have a red "x" on them.  Right click them, select modify connection and then take the defaults.

Visual Studio will then pull its head out of its hind parts, and those tables you've been saving that never appeared in the tables folder before will be auto-magically there.

Hope this helps.