# table isn't showing up in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I used Visual Studio 2010 and I am now returning to use 2012 and the book I am using is based for 2010, so a few things are different as far as instructions, but not much. However,

my problem is that I have created a table, and saved it from dbo.Table to "person" and it asks for a location to save the .sql file.

I've tried saving it in different locations but the table still doesn't appear under the Server Explorer -> Tables.

Any help is appreciated.

--Edit

Even if I save it as dbo.People, what location do I save it in for it to show up under Visual Studio's tables?

[image]

[image: Save Dialog Box]

Comment: you are creating a table called "Table"

Comment: it's been awhile for me, so i need to change dbo.Table to dbo.Person?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14591105/62576

Comment: Saving the file is not the same as running the command to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the table creation script on the database server VS is connected to not save it.